# I'm building a MineSweeper Project and i need help counting adjacent mines

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to count the adjacent mines in my Array of tiles objects. The code works fine for any section of the grid within the boundary. let's assume it's a 10 by 10 array if I pick point 9,8 it will give me an array out of bounds exception. How can I make sure the Array will count the Adjacent mines on the edge of the array without giving me an ArrayOutOfBounds exception?

```
void countAdjacentMines(int x,int y) {
        //Iterate through the array check if there is a mine
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tiles.length; j++) {
                if ((tiles[i][j].getMine() == false)) {
                    int count = 0;
                    //Search adjacent tiles. at x,y
                    for (int p = x - 1; p <= x + 1; p++) {
                        for (int q = y - 1; q <= y + 1; q++) {

                            if (0 <= p && p < tiles.length && 0 <= q && q < tiles.length) {
                                if (tiles[p][q].getMine()==true)
                                    count++;

                            }
                            tiles[p][q].setCount(count);
                        }                       
                    }                       
                }
            } // end for loop rows
        } // end for loop columns
  } // end countAdjacentMines
```

Comment: Come on, this is really obvious, check if `x-1`, `x+1`, `y-1` and `y+1` are in bounds ...

Comment: It would really help you (and everyone else) if you broke up your code into more manageable pieces.  For example, you should probably write a helper method to determine adjacent tiles.  Then you wouldn't have to think through nested for loops _four levels deep_ and you wouldn't need comments to mark the ends of loops.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function

`int hasMine (int x, int x)`

that returns 1 when `(x,y)` holds a mine,
or 0 if either it doesn't or (x,y) is not a valid cell (it is also useful
to have a `boolean valid (int x, int y)` function).

Then, just do:

`totalMines = hasMine(x+1,y+1) + hasMine(x+1, y) + hasMine(x+1, y-1) +  .... + hasMine (x-1,y-1)` // 8 hasMine() calls.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to

```
if (0 <= p && p < tiles.length && 0 <= q && q < tiles.length) {
    if (tiles[p][q].getMine()==true)
        count++;    
}
tiles[p][q].setCount(count);
```

where the last statement isn't guarded by the test that p and q are within bounds.

But I think that the entire method isn't right: either you need to iterate the entire board and count, or you access a single place (x,y) and do the count for this one.